# Sqoop incremental lastmodified not updating

Tags: sqoop

I am trying to run sqoop import with --incremental lastmodified, for updated and inserted records. Following is the table :

```
mysql> describe inc_lastmod_test;
+-------------------+-------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| Field             | Type        | Null | Key | Default           | Extra                       |
+-------------------+-------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| id                | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | 0                 |                             |
| value             | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| last_updated_date | timestamp   | NO   | MUL | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP | on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |
+-------------------+-------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
```

And the dataset in the table is :

```
mysql> select * from inc_lastmod_test;
+----+----------+---------------------+
| id | value    | last_updated_date   |
+----+----------+---------------------+
|  1 | first    | 2016-01-01 00:00:00 |
|  2 | second   | 2016-06-04 06:56:49 |
|  3 | newthird | 2016-06-04 07:06:40 |
|  4 | fourth   | 2016-01-04 00:00:00 |
|  5 | fifth    | 2016-01-05 00:00:00 |
|  6 | sixsth   | 2016-01-06 00:00:00 |
|  7 | seventh  | 2016-01-07 00:00:00 |
|  8 | eighth   | 2016-06-04 07:04:58 |
+----+----------+---------------------+
```

I previously imported table into HDFS which is in following state :

```
[cloudera@quickstart ~]$ hdfs dfs -cat /user/cloudera/inc_lastmod_test/part*
1,first,2016-01-01 00:00:00.0
2,second,2016-06-04 06:56:49.0
3,third,2016-01-03 00:00:00.0
4,fourth,2016-01-04 00:00:00.0
5,fifth,2016-01-05 00:00:00.0
6,sixsth,2016-01-06 00:00:00.0
7,seventh,2016-01-07 00:00:00.0
```

Based on the current state of data in mysql table, i expect to have
1)new record for id=8
2)updated record for id=3 (with changed value)
in HDFS dir

However, it only seems to have inserted all the records and not updating existing records after running following command :

```
    [cloudera@quickstart ~]$ sqoop import \
--connect "jdbc:mysql://quickstart.cloudera:3306/retail_db" \
--username retail_dba \
--password cloudera \
--table inc_lastmod_test \
--append \
--incremental lastmodified \
--check-column last_updated_date \
--last-value "2016-01-08 00:00:00"
```

Please tell me where I am going wrong?

Comment: Can anyone please help with this?

Comment: Unfortunately, this question never got answered.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
   [cloudera@quickstart ~]$ sqoop import \
--connect "jdbc:mysql://quickstart.cloudera:3306/retail_db" \
--username retail_dba \
--password cloudera \
--table inc_lastmod_test \
--append \
--incremental lastmodified \
--check-column last_updated_date \
--last-value "2016-01-08 00:00:00.0"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  sqoop import \
--connect "jdbc:mysql://quickstart.cloudera:3306/retail_db" \
--username retail_dba \
--password cloudera \
--table inc_lastmod_test \
--append \
--incremental lastmodified \
--check-column last_updated_date \
--last-value "2016-01-08 00:00:00
```

Incremental updates doesn't modify the existing file (/user/cloudera/inc_lastmod_test/part*). It fetches all the records which got modified on and after the given date and write them to new file.

Comment: I think you are executing sqoop jobs in parallel  that's why it is not updating sqoop metastore.

Why don't you try external metastore for sqoop ...Like You can use postgres for sqoop's metastore.